# Conditioning to derive the distribution of function of uniform random variables

Tags: self-study, distributions, uniform-distribution

After seeing this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52897896/how-to-plot-pdf-of-uniform-random-variables-in-matlab/52899777#52899777), I was genuinely curious if there was a way to derive this distribution.

I've attempted it below using the CDF for $Z$ and conditioning on the value of $Y$.  It is unclear to me if it would have been easier to condition on the value of $X$.

Denote the CDF as $F_X(x) \equiv P(X\le x)$ and the PDF as $f_X(x)$. Let $\bar F_X(x) = P(X>x) = 1-F_X(x)$.

**Question:**
Let $X\sim U(0,1)$, $Y\sim U(0,1)$, and $X$ & $Y$ be independent.
Define
$$Z\equiv \text{cos}(2\pi Y)\left[-2\text{ln}(X)\right]^2$$

What is the distribution of $Z$? Goal is to get PDF.

**My first attempt:**

$\begin{align}
F_Z(z) &\equiv P(Z\le z) = P(\text{cos}(2\pi Y)\left[-2\text{ln}(X)\right]^2\le z) \\
&=\int_0^1 P(\text{cos}(2\pi Y)\left[-2\text{ln}(X)\right]^2\le z|Y = y)f_Y(y)dy \\
&=\int_0^1 P\left(X \ge \text{e}^{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{z}{\text{cos}(2\pi y)}}}\right)dy  \\
&\vdots \\
&(\text{Algebra}) \\
&\vdots \\
&= \int_0^1 \bar F_X\left(\text{e}^{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{z}{\text{cos}(2\pi y)}}} \right)dy \\
&= \int_0^1 1-\text{e}^{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{z}{\text{cos}(2\pi y)}}} dy 
\end{align}$

I was unable to resolve this.  My next attempt will condition on $X=x$ to see if that simplifies any better. I've added the `self-study` tag since this is for my curiosity (this is not for an assignment).

**Update:**
On suggestion from helpful commenters, I'm trying the Jacobian Determinant approach based on [p. 5-7 here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/Stat/StatLec1-5.pdf) and [the last page here](https://www.stat.washington.edu/~nehemyl/files/UW_MATH-STAT395_functions-random-variables.pdf).  Never seen this approach before, but here goes...

Set $W = Y$ and we know $X = \text{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{Z}{\text{cos}(2\pi Y)}}}= \text{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{Z}{\text{cos}(2\pi W)}}}$.

The method gives the joint density $$f_{Z,W}(z,w)= \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{|\mathbf{J}|}$$ where 
$$\mathbf{J}= \left[ {\begin{array}{c c}
\partial z/ \partial x & \partial z/ \partial y  \\
\partial w/ \partial x  & \partial w/ \partial y  
\end{array} }\right] = 
\left[ {\begin{array}{c c}
\frac{8\text{ln}(x)\text{cos}(2 \pi y)}{x} & -8\pi \text{ln}^2(x)\text{sin}(2 \pi y)  \\
0  & 1  
\end{array} }\right]
$$
so $|\mathbf{J}| = \frac{8\text{ln}(x)\text{cos}(2 \pi y)}{x}$.

Now this gives us 
$$\begin{align} f_{Z,W}(z,w) &= \frac{f_X\left(\text{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{z}{\text{cos}(2\pi y)}}}\right)f_Y(w)x}{8\text{ln}(x)\text{cos}(2 \pi y)} \\
\\
&=\frac{f_X\left(\text{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{z}{\text{cos}(2\pi w)}}}\right)\text{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{z}{\text{cos}(2\pi w)}}}f_Y(w)}{8\text{ln}\left(\text{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{z}{\text{cos}(2\pi w)}}}\right)\text{cos}(2 \pi w)}
\end{align}$$
But we know $f_X(x) = x$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and similarly with $f_Y(y)$. Then 
$$f_{Z,W}(z,w) =\frac{w\,\text{e}^{-\sqrt{\frac{z}{\text{cos}(2\pi w)}}}}{8\text{ln}\left(\text{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{z}{\text{cos}(2\pi w)}}}\right)\text{cos}(2 \pi w)}$$

for $w\in [0,1]$. Now to find the marginal distribution $f_Z(z)$ from 
$$\begin{align}f_Z(z)&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{Z,W}(z,w)dw \\
&=\int_0^1 f_{Z,W}(z,w)dw
\end{align}$$

This will take me some time.

Comment: Did you try the Jacobian Determinant method?

Comment: No I haven't heard of that method but I'll look it up.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: See here, last page, maybe it is useful for your case. https://www.stat.washington.edu/~nehemyl/files/UW_MATH-STAT395_functions-random-variables.pdf

Comment: Thanks, also looking at this...https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/Stat/StatLec1-5.pdf

Comment: I think this method is easier than CDF->PDF if applicable.

Comment: Consider $2\pi Y$ to be a random angle, and the other term to be a radius. Then you're computing one component of a conversion to Cartesian co-ordinates. If the second term was to the power of 1/2 rather than 2 it's very easy, but if that power is definitely 2 you should still be able to get there; the second term in the product is plainly the square of a chi-squared(2) variate.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b, based on the OP from SO, that power was 1/2 rather than 2.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Box-MullerTransformation.html